# how to set cursor position to its default

Tags: c++, cursor-position

I have used gotoxy() function to set cursor position to specific points that help me to reorder the values as shown in picture . Now I want the "press any key to continue" statement and the referred zero value to be set at the bottom of the screen how I can do this

[image]

Here is the code for gotoxy() function:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) 
{ 
COORD coord;
coord.X = x; 
coord.Y = y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current position using [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Something like:

```
COORD GetXY()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info);
    return info.dwCursorPosition;
}
```

Comment: @Mast Petersson it's still like it was

Comment: What exactly does your program do "now"? Let me guess, you are just calling the `GetXY` function, without using the result? Perhaps you should try:
`COORD old = GetXY();  ... do stuff ... gotoxy(old.X, old.Y);`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your gotoxy() works.

So simply set the cursor to "top left" of the screen (or to your favorite location?) prior to prompting for "press any key to continue".

You own the cursor!